# How To Create an Exchange 2010 Email That Just Distributes Its Received Emails to Other Users?

Tags: exchange-server, windows-server-2008-r2

How do you accomplish setting up an Exchange email that is made just to have users send email to it, then have that email automatically distribute received emails to specified email addresses?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  I need to create a distribution group within the Exchange 2010 ECP (Exchange Control Panel) by going to remote.mydomain.com/ecp and creating a distribution group with the desired associated users.